# What's wrong with my jQuery code ? My loop isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have tried to correct the jQuery code below. In the ESNList text field, multiple values need to be entered separated with a comma, yet they have to be in the same range. For example, in the condition below in the loop, if you input a number in ESNList between 986329 and 999999, the second input in the ESNList field should be in the same range as the first input and so on otherwise I throw an alert saying that both ESNs should be in the same range. I did a loop to perform the check but it's not working. Can someone demonstrate to me where the error is? A fiddle would help tons, I have a hard time sometimes understanding what people try to say on here without good demonstration of where I went wrong. Below is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {


    $(":text").css("border", "2px solid red");
      $(":text").keyup(function(){
        var enteredData = $(this).val()
        console.log(enteredData);
        if (enteredData == "") {
          $(this).css("border", "2px solid red");
        } else {
          $(this).css("border", "inherit");
        }
        if ($(this).attr("id") == "ESNList"){
       esnList = enteredData.split(',');
           }
           
           for(var i = 0; i < esnList.length; i++) {
            if  ( parseInt(esnList[i]) >= 986329 && parseInt(esnList[i]) <= 999999) {
                $("#ddl_StxName").val("stx2");
                $("#ddl_rtumodel").val("globalstar");
                }
            else if ( parseInt(esnList[i]) >= 660000 && parseInt(esnList[i]) <= 699999) {
                $("#ddl_StxName").val("mmt");
                $("#ddl_rtumodel").val("globalstar");
                 }
            else if ( parseInt(esnList[i]) >= 200000 && parseInt(esnList[i]) <= 299999) {
                $("#ddl_StxName").val("stm3");
                $("#ddl_rtumodel").val("stmcomtech");
                 }
            else if ( parseInt(esnList[i]) >= 1202114 && parseInt(esnList[i]) <= 1299999) {
                $("#ddl_StxName").val("smartone");
                $("#ddl_rtumodel").val("globalstar");
          }
          
          else { alert("ESNs should be within the same range"); }
          
        }
        

      });
      });
    </script> </head>
    <body>
    <form id="provision">
        ESNList:    <input  type="text" id="ESNList" name="ESNList" size="30" /> <br />
        ESN Start:<input type="text" id="ESNStart" name="ESNStart" size="10" /> <br />
        ESN End: <input type="text" id="ESNStart" name="ESNStart" size="10" /> <br />
        UnitName:<input type="text" id="STxName" name="STxName" size="30"  />  <br />  
         Unit Model:   <select name="STxName" id="ddl_StxName">
        <option value="stx2">STX2</option>
        <option value="stm3" selected>STM3</option>
        <option value="acutec">Acutec</option>
         <option value="trackpack">Trackpack</option>
        <option value="mmt">MMT</option>
        <option value="smartone">Smartone</option>
        <option value="smartoneb" >SmartOneB</option>
        </select> <br />
        RTU Model Type:
         <select name="rtumodel" id ="ddl_rtumodel">
        <option value="globalstar">GlobalStar</option>
        <option value="both">Both</option>
        <option value="comtech">Comtech</option>
        <option value="stmcomtech">STMComtech</option>
        </select> <br />
        <input type="submit" value ="submit"  />
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: A good place to start might be here: `ellse { alert("ESNs should be within the same range"); }`. A javascript debugger would have pointed *that* mistake out instantly. Also indent your code more carefully - it helps loads in spotting mismatched braces and things like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this for debugging:

before the `for(...)` line, put

```
console.log(esnList.length);
```

then after the `for(...)` line:

```
console.log("entering for loop, i = " + i );
```

these will be written to the javascript console, which you can view in the developer tools of most browsers. Include similar logging in your if/else statements, and you can narrow down where the problem is yourself by seeing which of these is triggered.

You're on the right track with the `alert()` you use, just use that or `console.log()` more often.

Comment: could u help me figure out how to make sure that the several inputs separated by commas are in the same range otherwise an alert is thrown to ask to user to make sure they're in the same range ?